# Writing a list of lists to a file with a new line per element

Tags: python

```
    file = open("myfile.txt","w")
    aList = [["Hello","1","2"],["Hello","3","4"],["Hello","5","6"]]

    for element in aList:
        file.writelines("\n".join(element))
```

The way it comes out on the textfile:

```
Hello
1
2Hello
3
4Hello
5
6
```

They way i would like it to come out on the textfile:

```
Hello
1
2
Hello
3
4
Hello
5
6
```

What am I doing wrong in my for loop and how can i fix it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `write` instead of `writelines`. `writelines` might happen to work anyway by iterating over the string and writing each character, but it's intended to be used to write a list of separate lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
aList = [["Hello","1","2"],["Hello","3","4"],["Hello","5","6"]]
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for e in itertools.chain.from_iterable(aList):
        outfile.write(e+'\n')
```

Comment: `write('\n'.join(chain.from_iterable(aList)))` will write list without the need of a loop

Comment: But that would create a string whose size grows with the size of `aList`. If this gets very big, it becomes very memory inefficient

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new line after every `element`:

```
for element in aList:
    file.writelines("\n".join(element))
    file.write("\n")
```